# Inconsistent duplicated row on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm having a weird behavior with Apache Spark, which I run in a Python Notebook on Azure Databricks. I have a dataframe with some data, with 2 columns of interest: name and ftime

I found that I sometime have duplicated values, sometime not, depending on how I fetch the data:

```py
df.where(col('name') == 'test').where(col('ftime') == '2022-07-18').count()
# Result is 1
```

But when I run

```py
len(df.where(col('name') == 'test').where(col('ftime') == '2022-07-18').collect())
# Result is 2
```

, I now have a result of 2 rows, which are exactly the same. Those two cells are ran one after the other, the order doesn't change anything.

I tried creating a temp view in spark with

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df_referential')
```

but I run in the same problem:

```sql
%sql
SELECT name, ftime, COUNT(*)
FROM df_referential
GROUP BY name, ftime
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

returns no result, while

```sql
%sql
SELECT *
FROM df_referential
WHERE name = 'test' AND ftime = '2022-07-18'
```

returns two rows, perfectly identical.

I'm having a hard time understanding why this happens. I expect these to returns only one row, and the JSON file that the data is read from contains only one occurrence of the data.
If someone can point me at what I'm doing wrong, this would be of great help

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you use `.filter((col('name') == 'test') && (col('ftime') == '2022-07-18'))`?

Comment: I'm in python so I guess you meant ```.filter((col('name') == 'test') & (col('ftime') == '2022-07-18'))```, but this returns the same thing as the double where method @Andrew

Comment: I tried code and queries used above and they have returned the result that is expected when run on a small dataframe. Can you recheck the data and please provide sample data if possible

Comment: Could you show the output of  `df.where(...).where(...).show()`? Do you happen to have `_corrupt_record`?

Comment: Here is the data loading code I'm using: ```df = spark.read.json(referential_files)\
        .withColumn("data", F.explode("skills")).select("data.*")\
        .withColumn('categories', cat_extract('categories'))```(cat_extract is an udf),

Comment: And no I do not have a corrupt record Emma

Comment: And if I try to ```df.filter((col('name') == 'test') & (col('ftime') == '2022-07-18')).show()``` I have 2 rows, but ```df.filter((col('name') == 'test') & (col('ftime') == '2022-07-18')).select('name', 'ftime').show()``` returns only one

Comment: Could you add the output of `df.filter((col('name') == 'test') & (col('ftime') == '2022-07-18')).show()` in the question?  If you have too much columns, try to show at least 10? 

as much as I experienced, this behavior happens when you have corrupt records in other columns than `name` and `ftime`.  It will be easier to spot if you see the whole table when you see 2 rows.

Comment: Sadly this is customer data, that I'm not allowed to displayed. Is there anyway I could look for a corrupt record ? What should I expect to find in this case ?

Comment: you could mask values or put random text in place of the real record but keep same texts for the same record.  
Though, you can try to look for the columns that have different values between the 2 rows.  Anything odd there?  ref: https://medium.com/@smdbilal.vt5815/csv-bad-record-handling-and-its-complications-pyspark-f3b871d652ba

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246780/discussion-between-papotitu-and-emma).